# Loop through worksheets with a specific name

Tags: vba, excel

Say I have 10 worksheets and 4 have very similar names:

> 1.danger tom
>   2.danger man
>   3.danger ten
>   4.danger lan

I want my code to find all worksheets with the text string *danger* in its name and execute my code

I've tried the following two instances:

```
Public Sub SubName()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    If ws.Name Like "danger" Then
       *Also tried this version: If ws.Name Like "danger" = True Then*

        Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 37
    End If

Next ws

End Sub
```

*take 2*

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

Dim ws  As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If InStr("danger", ws.Name) > 0 Then
        Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 37
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

The first code doesn't do anything, even though there's no errors. The second code only does something if the name matches exactly with what I wrote down.

Any help is needed.

Comment: What's wrong with the second one exactly? It does what you want?

Comment: @findwindow - he needs to add the `ws.` before each `Range()`, otherwise it just runs on the active sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Your first code will work if you change this:

```
 If ws.Name Like "danger" Then
   *Also tried this version: If ws.Name Like "danger" = True Then*

    Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 37
End If
```

to this :

```
If ws.Name Like "danger" & "*" Then    
     ws.Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 37
End If
```

and simply you can use "danger*".

Comment: @Daruki - This may not work exactly as you want (the first one anyways), unless you add the `ws.` before ` Range("A1")...`.

Comment: Thanks @BruceWayne , But I changed the answer before your comment

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure you just need to add in explicitly which worksheets you're using.

```
Public Sub SubName()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "danger" Then
      ' *Also tried this version: If ws.Name Like "danger" = True Then*
        ws.Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 37
    End If
Next ws

End Sub

Sub WorksheetLoop()

Dim ws  As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If InStr("danger", ws.Name) > 0 Then
        ws.Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 37
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

It's a simple fix (all I did was add `ws.` before each `Range()`), but **very important** when working with multiple sheets.  Always be explicit when using multiple ranges. If you were using `Cells()`, `Row()`,`Column()`, etc. you should add the worksheet you're using as well.

An alternative layout is using `With` (see below for example with your `SubName()` routine):

```
Public Sub SubName()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
    If .Name Like "danger" Then
      ' *Also tried this version: If ws.Name Like "danger" = True Then*
        .Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 37
      ' For illusatration, this will color the range A1:B10
      ' .Range(.Cells(1,1),.Cells(10,2)).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
    End If
    End with
Next ws

End Sub
```

Notice that using `With` allows you to just use a "placeholder" `.` to refer to the `WS` (or whatever follows `With`).  See the line I added that uses `Range(Cells(),Cells())` for a good example of this.

Edit: Using `If ws.Name like "danger" Then` will *only* run on sheets named `danger` (lowercase, no spaces).  If you want this to work on sheets named like `DangerMouse`, `DangerDoom`, `Carlos Danger`, then you'll need to use `... Like "*danger*" Then`

Comment: @BruceWayne, unfortunately the code doesn't do what I want it to. the first code `subname()` doesn't do anything, while the second one `worksheetloop` only executes my code when the worksheet name matches exactly with the text string I entered in the code - i.e. when the worksheet name is danger, only then it will execute, it won't execute when the worksheet name is danger man

Comment: @Daruki - Are you aware that this will only change sheet names that are `danger`, lowercase, without anything else? Are you trying to run this on `dangerMouse`, `dangerDoom`, `danger Man` sheet type names?

Comment: @Daruki - See my edit regarding the sheet names. Does that help?

Comment: @BruceWayne, I tried both of your code edits but none could work. Basically, i wanted my code to execute whenever a sheet name had "danger" in it - `dangermouse`, `danger man`, `123 me danger`, etc..

Answer (score 1):

Or without looping

```
Sub GetSheets()
Dim strIn As String
Dim X, xArr

strIn = Application.InputBox("Search string", "Enter string to find", "*List*", , , , , 2)
If strIn = "False" Then Exit Sub

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add "shtNames", "=RIGHT(GET.WORKBOOK(1),LEN(GET.WORKBOOK(1))-FIND(""]"",GET.WORKBOOK(1)))"
X = Filter([index(shtNames,)], strIn, True, 1)

For Each xArr In X
Sheets(xArr).Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 37
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an asterisk `*` before the `like` name. e.g. .`Name Like "*danger"`

Asterisk `*` is the wildcard for Excel