# How to loop through sheets in a workbook with an exception?

Tags: excel, vba

The following code loops within a sheet.

I want to loop through all sheets in my workbook except for one sheet labeled "Summary".

```vb
For i = 2 To LR
    
    If Abs(Range("J" & i)) > 0 Then
        Range("A" & i & ":J" & i).Copy
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                
        k = k + 1
    
    Else
    
    End If
                   
Next i
```

Comment: Loop through the Workbook.Sheets collection - you should be able to find many examples online.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through worksheets with a specific name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298924/loop-through-worksheets-with-a-specific-name)

Answer (score 2):

Please try something like this

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
    'Your code here
    End If
Next
```