# Looping thru Excel worksheets in a Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I import my master sheet daily and at the bottom of my master sheet I calculate totals. Underneath that I calculate averages. I then perform two other average calculations at the bottom of column A and B. I then split my table according to the marketplaces and my program then opens a new tab for each marketplace. I've then managed to split my table so that the data goes into the correct tab. I now want to perform the identical total and average calculations on each of the marketplaces. Marketplaces are a dynamic value - The program might open 8 if there have been sales on 8 marketplaces, or 5 if....etc. This code performs the sum and average row calculations but NOT the other average calculations at the bottom of column A and B. I can't get that to work.

*Update.... I've addressed this section of the problem - I hadn't realised there is a sheet.count function*

*Also as the number of sheets in the workbook is dynamic and I want to perform the calculations from sheets 3 to the end of the workbook I've used n as a variable and have a for n = 3 to 10  statement in there but there must be a way to assign the number of sheets in the workbook to n?*

```
Sub CalcOnSheets()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim row As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ActiveWorksheet As Long
Dim ThisWorksheet As Long
Dim n As Integer



'I've put 3 to 10 here because I don't know how to count the actual number of sheets that I want to 
'run this for Is there a variable which is the count of the sheets in the workbook, as this value is 
'dynamic?

For n = 3 To 10
lastRow = Sheets(n).Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row
If lastRow > 1 Then
For row = 2 To lastRow

'I've got row 4 in here so the calculations stop performing
'when the iteration gets down to the blank row under the sheet
'but I'm not sure if it's necessary. Could maybe take out the if and the end if

If Sheets(n).Cells(row, 4).Value <> "" Then

Sheets(n).Cells(row, 16).Value = Sheets(n).Cells(row, 10).Value - Sheets(n).Cells(row, 11).Value - _
Sheets(n).Cells(row, 12).Value - Sheets(n).Cells(row, 13).Value - Sheets(n).Cells(row, 14).Value - _
Sheets(n).Cells(row, 15).Value
Sheets(n).Cells(row, 17).Value = Sheets(n).Cells(row, 16).Value / Sheets(n).Cells(row, 10).Value

End If


Next

Dim r As range, j As Long, k As Long
j = Sheets(n).range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column



'This adds up the totals on the sheet
'changing the first value of k stops it adding up un-needed columns
 For k = 9 To j
 Set r = Sheets(n).range(Sheets(n).Cells(1, k), Sheets(n).Cells(1, k).End(xlDown))
 r.End(xlDown).Offset(2, 0) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(r)
 r.End(xlDown).Offset(3, 0) = WorksheetFunction.Average(r)
 Next k


'This deletes the total of the profit margins whch is meaningless
Sheets(n).range("Q" & lastRow).Offset(2) = ""


'This changes the format of column I average value back to two decimal places
 Sheets(n).range("I" & lastRow).Offset(3).NumberFormat = "0.00_);(0.00)"


'These don't work....
'This calculates Average profit per unit
'Sheets(n).range("B" & lastRow).Offset(2, 0).Value = Sheets(n).range("P" & lastRow).Offset(2).Value / Sheets(n).range("I" 
& lastRow).Offset(2).Value
'This calculates Average profit per order
'Sheets(n).range("A" & lastRow).Offset(2, 0).Value = Sheets(n).range("P" & lastRow).Offset(2).Value / Sheets(n).range("D2").End(xlDown).row



Else

MsgBox ("There is no data at column D")
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


Next n

End Sub
```

I'm quite inexperienced with VBA and just finding my way around. I'd also like to know if there's a simple way to widen SOME columns so my fit (Columns 10 to 17)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA loop through sheets in a workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50568733/vba-loop-through-sheets-in-a-workbook)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the sheet.count function which helped me with the dynamic number of worksheets that I was struggling with:

```
Dim x As Integer
x = Sheets.Count
For n = 3 To x
next x
```

I also spotted that I had a mistake in this line:

```
range("I" & lastRow).Offset(2).Value
```

Which should have been:

```
Sheets(n).range("I" & lastRow).Offset(2).Value
```