# How to multiselect Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I need to be the name of worksheets are multiple.
Because the original template sometimes named "Parts" sometimes names "Function Manifold" or got a few names more.

Basically, the name of the worksheet is got three or four different name.

Now, i only know how to use only one Worksheet name - "Parts"

```
Sub CopyFilesContent()
   Dim oFSO As Object, oFolder As Object, oFile As Object, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
   Dim i As Long, j As Long, LR As Long, lastR As Long, wsFN As Worksheet

   Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\user name\Downloads\Test Consolidate Folder\2021")
   Set wsFN = Workbooks("Consolidate.xlsm").Worksheets("Master")
   
   For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open(oFile)    'open the workbook to copy from

################################## THIS PART PLEASE HELP ###################################

       Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Parts") 'Parts sheet, to copy from. Use here the necessary one if not this
      
       LR = wsFN.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1       'last empty row in the master FileName sheet
       wsFN.Cells(LR) = oFile.Name                            'write the wb to copy from name
       lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 2 'last row in the sheet where to copy from
       
       
       
       ws.Cells(4, 13).FormulaR1C1 = "=MATCH(1,C[-12],0)"
       ws.Cells(4, 13).Copy
       Cells(4, 13).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
       
       firstR = ws.Cells(4, 13)
       
       ws.Cells(3, 13).Copy
       Range("K" & firstR & ":K" & lastR).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
       ws.Range("A10:N" & lastR).Copy wsFN.Range("A" & LR + 1) 'copy the necessary range
       wb.Close False  'close the workbook, without saving it
   Next oFile
   
   
       Columns("A:A").Select
       Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
       Selection.EntireRow.Delete
   
End Sub
```

After some comment below , I've tried by doing this code
But when I debug, it didn't go in to the worksheet that named "Parts".

please help

[image]

And I updated the code as suggested by @VBasic2008,
But still the code didn't go in even though got worksheet name as I declare below "Parts"

```
Sub CopyFilesContent()
    
    Const ProcTitle As String = "Copy Files Contents"
    Const wsNamesList As String = "Parts,Function Manifold,Manifolding,Whatever"
    
    Dim oFSO As Object, oFolder As Object, oFile As Object, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, LR As Long, lastR As Long, wsFN As Worksheet

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\user name\Downloads\Test Consolidate Folder\2021")
    Set wsFN = Workbooks("Consolidate.xlsm").Worksheets("Master")
    
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(oFile)    'open the workbook to copy from
        Set ws = RefFirstExistingWorksheet(wb, wsNamesList)
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
        
            LR = wsFN.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1       'last empty row in the master FileName sheet
            wsFN.Cells(LR) = oFile.Name                            'write the wb to copy from name
            lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 2 'last row in the sheet where to copy from
        
        
        
            ws.Cells(4, 13).FormulaR1C1 = "=MATCH(1,C[-12],0)"
            ws.Cells(4, 13).Copy
            Cells(4, 13).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        
            firstR = ws.Cells(4, 13)
        
            ws.Cells(3, 13).Copy
            Range("K" & firstR & ":K" & lastR).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            ws.Range("A10:N" & lastR).Copy wsFN.Range("A" & LR + 1) 'copy the necessary range

            wb.Close False  'close the workbook, without saving it
        Else
            MsgBox "Parts worksheet not found in file '" & oFile.Name & "'.", _
                vbCritical, ProcTitle
        End If
    Next oFile
   
        Columns("A:A").Select
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    
End Sub

Function RefFirstExistingWorksheet( _
    ByVal wb As Workbook, _
    ByVal WorksheetNamesList As String, _
    Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = "Parts,Function Manifold") _
As Worksheet
    If wb Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If Len(WorksheetNamesList) = 0 Then Exit Function
    Dim wsNames() As String: wsNames = Split(WorksheetNamesList, Delimiter)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsName As Variant
    For Each wsName In wsNames
        On Error Resume Next
        Set RefFirstExistingWorksheet = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not RefFirstExistingWorksheet Is Nothing Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wsName
End Function
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50568733/vba-loop-through-sheets-in-a-workbook

Comment: @braX Please see my amendment of coding above. Please help.

Comment: When you put a breakpoint on the `If` statement and look at `ws.Name` - Maybe your sheet name has a space in the front of it or at the end of it? You are going to need to debug it like normal. Check the variables as you go.

Comment: @braX Because I've tried to run the script and the Master page is empty. Not what suppose to have. Meaning the code didn't go in.

Comment: `Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = ","` stays `Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = ","`. The comma (no spaces) is representing the delimiter between the possible worksheet names. You said 4 possible worksheet names yet you left the 2 dummy names: `Manifolding` and `Whatever`. The rest looks ok.

Comment: I got it! So happy! Thanks brilliant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reference First Existing Worksheet

- In your `CopyFilesContent` procedure, you could utilize the `RefFirstExistingWorksheet` function. Try testing as is, and afterward add the rest of the code.

```vb
Sub CopyFilesContent()
    
    Const ProcTitle As String = "Copy Files Contents"
    Const wsNamesList As String = "Parts,Function Manifold,Manifolding,Whatever"
    
    Dim oFSO As Object, oFolder As Object, oFile As Object, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, LR As Long, lastR As Long, wsFN As Worksheet

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\user name\Downloads\Test Consolidate Folder\2021")
    Set wsFN = Workbooks("Consolidate.xlsm").Worksheets("Master")
    
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(oFile)    'open the workbook to copy from
        Set ws = RefFirstExistingWorksheet(wb, wsNamesList)
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
            ' Remove when done testing:
            MsgBox "Found worksheet '" & ws.Name & "'.", _
                vbInformation, ProcTitle
            ' Continue...
            'LR = ...

            wb.Close False  'close the workbook, without saving it
        Else
            MsgBox "Parts worksheet not found in file '" & oFile.Name & "'.", _
                vbCritical, ProcTitle
        End If
    Next oFile
    
    ' Continue
    'Columns...
    
End Sub

Function RefFirstExistingWorksheet( _
    ByVal wb As Workbook, _
    ByVal WorksheetNamesList As String, _
    Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = ",") _
As Worksheet
    If wb Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If Len(WorksheetNamesList) = 0 Then Exit Function
    Dim wsNames() As String: wsNames = Split(WorksheetNamesList, Delimiter)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsName As Variant
    For Each wsName In wsNames
        On Error Resume Next
        Set RefFirstExistingWorksheet = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not RefFirstExistingWorksheet Is Nothing Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wsName
End Function
```

Here's a tester to better understand the function: in a new workbook, add this code to a standard module. Now, add sheets, rename them and modify `wsNamesList` etc.

```
Sub Tester()
    Const wsNamesList As String = "Sheet150,Sheet22,Sheet1"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = RefFirstExistingWorksheet(wb, wsNamesList)
    
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print ws.Name
    Else
        Debug.Print "Nope"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, please see my updated coding above, still not go in with the name of worksheet.