# VBA to pull values from a variable number of worksheets with similar names from multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, variables, copy-paste, worksheet

I want to use VBA to create a summary sheet in this workbook (storage workbook) that I am currently working in to go through multiple reports (over 100) and pull certain values.

Each report contains 10+ sheets, but I am only interested in copying cells A4:A5 from the sheets titled Day1, Day2, Day3, etc.

I found success using the code below and creating a module for each Day 1, Day 2, Day 3, etc.

```vb
Sub Day1_values()

Dim basebook As Workbook
Dim mybook As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim rnum As Long
Dim FNames As String
Dim MyPath As String
Dim SaveDriveDir As String
Dim Cnum As Integer
Dim cell As Range
Dim foldername As String
Dim getpath As String
Dim myFilePath As String

SaveDriveDir = CurDir
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If .Show = -1 Then
        MyPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
   End With
   

If MyPath <> "" Then

ChDrive MyPath
ChDir MyPath

FNames = Dir("*.xlsm")
If Len(FNames) = 0 Then
MsgBox "No files in the Directory"
ChDrive SaveDriveDir
ChDir SaveDriveDir
Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set basebook = ThisWorkbook

rnum = 2

Do While FNames <> ""
Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(FNames)

' This will add the workbook name in column A
basebook.Worksheets(1).Cells(rnum, "A").Value = mybook.Name
basebook.Worksheets(1).Cells(rnum, "B").Value = mybook.Path

Cnum = 3 'begin pasting the values in column 3

For Each cell In mybook.Worksheets("Day1").Range("A4:A5")
    basebook.Worksheets(1).Cells(rnum, Cnum).Value = cell.Value
    Cnum = Cnum + 1
    Next cell
    
    mybook.Close False
    rnum = rnum + 1
    FNames = Dir()
    Loop

ChDrive SaveDriveDir
ChDir SaveDriveDir
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End If
End Sub
```

The problem is that each workbook contains a different number of days. For example report 1 has day1 - day5 and report 2 only has day1 - day2.

The above code doesn't work when I create a module for Day3 because it will see that report 2 does not have a Day3 and the code will break because `subscript out of range`.

Does anyone have any idea how I can manipulate the code in a way to say that for each workbook, if the sheet name contains *Day** to copy cells A4:A5 and paste them in my storage workbook?

There was a similar post here: [Loop through worksheets with a specific name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298924/loop-through-worksheets-with-a-specific-name) and they successfully used this code for their problem:

```
If ws.Name Like "danger" & "*" Then    
     ws.Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 37
End If
```

I just don't know how to add that into my existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```vb
Sub ImportWorksheetData()

    Dim basebook As Workbook, mybook As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim rwResults As Range, nm As String, f

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = -1 Then
            MyPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    If Len(MyPath) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'no folder chosen
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\" 'ensure trailing \
    
    Set basebook = ThisWorkbook
    Set rwResults = basebook.Worksheets(1).Rows(2)
    
    f = Dir(MyPath & "*.xlsm")
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & f)
        For Each ws In mybook.Worksheets
            'Does the worksheet name match our pattern?
            nm = UCase(Replace(ws.Name, " ", "")) 'ignore spaces when checking
            If nm Like "DAY#" Or nm Like "DAY##" Then  '# = any digit
                rwResults.Columns("A").Value = f
                rwResults.Columns("B").Value = MyPath
                rwResults.Columns("C").Value = ws.Name
                rwResults.Columns("D").Value = ws.Range("A4").Value
                rwResults.Columns("E").Value = ws.Range("A5").Value
                Set rwResults = rwResults.Offset(1, 0) 'move down for next sheet
            End If
        Next ws
        
        mybook.Close False 'no save
        f = Dir()
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Collect Data from Workbooks

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CollectData()

    Const sPattern As String = "*.xlsm"
    Const swsPatternLCase As String = "day*"
    Const sAddressesList As String = "A4,A5" ' add more
    
    Const dID As Variant = 1 ' or e.g. "Sheet1" - is safer
    Const dFirst As String = "A2" ' Destination First Cell Address
    Const dLower As Long = 3 ' first column to write the cell values to
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sPath As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .InitialFileName = dwb.Path & "\"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            sPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    If sPath = "" Then Exit Sub ' dialog canceled
    
    Dim sName As String: sName = Dir(sPath & "\" & sPattern)
    If Len(sName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files in the Directory"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim sAddresses() As String: sAddresses = Split(sAddressesList, ",")
    Dim aUpper As Long: aUpper = UBound(sAddresses)
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = dLower + aUpper
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim Dat As Variant: ReDim Dat(1 To cCount)
    
    Dim swb As Workbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long
    Dim a As Long
    
    ' Write each worksheet's results to an array ('Dat') and add the array
    ' to the dictionary ('dict').
    Do While sName <> ""
        Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sPath & "\" & sName)
        Dat(1) = swb.Name
        Dat(2) = sPath ' or swb.Path - it's always the same '***
        For Each sws In swb.Worksheets
            If LCase(sws.Name) Like swsPatternLCase Then
                'Dat(2) = sws.Name ' looks more useful '***
                For a = 0 To aUpper
                    Dat(dLower + a) = sws.Range(sAddresses(a)).Value
                Next a
                n = n + 1
                dict.Add n, Dat
            End If
        Next sws
        swb.Close False
        sName = Dir()
    Loop
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = dict.Count
    
    If rCount > 0 Then
        
        ' Write the results from the arrays in the dictionary
        ' to a 2D one-based array ('dData').
        Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To cCount)
        Dim r As Long
        Dim c As Long
        For Each Dat In dict.Items
            r = r + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                dData(r, c) = Dat(c)
            Next c
        Next Dat
        
        With dwb.Worksheets(dID).Range(dFirst).Resize(, cCount)
            ' Write the results to the destination range (in one go).
            .Resize(rCount).Value = dData
            ' Clear the contents below the destination range.
            .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - rCount + 1) _
                .Offset(rCount).ClearContents
            .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With

        dwb.Save
    
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Data collected.", vbInformation, "Collect Data"
    
End Sub
```